# Using typedef in a program

Tags: c, typedef, structure

Yesterday I had my exam's and there was a question like this:
Write a program using typedef to find out the larger of two numbers.

So the solution to this problem is obvious right? But we have to use typedef thats the condition, So this is what i did.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
}LARGE;

void main()
{
    LARGE a,b;
    int c;
    scanf("%d%d", &a.a,&b.a);
    c = large(a.a,b.a);
    printf("%d", c);
}
```

This is the main program and I have written a function named large() that returns largest of two numbers.

This is how I added the keyword typedef in my program, but the department teachers says we should use typedef to create new names and not use it in structures i,e:

```
typedef int large a,b;
```

now large is a new name for int.

But the question does not explicitly specify to use typedef to create new name for the data types being used, so i wrote the program using structures using typedef, so please let me know what is the right way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obviously, Your teacher messed it.The Q asked *"program using `typedef`"*. Your program does that.It qualify's as an answer to the Q that was asked.

Comment: I agree; while your solution is not the most obvious way (``typedef`` on a struct is basically just a way to avoid having to type ``struct`` each time), it's nevertheless not incorrect, given the vague way the question is phrased

Comment: Ok thanks so what you are saying is my answer is right according to the question, which was to write a program to return largest of two numbers using typedef, so i have written a program that returns largest of two numbers using typedef

Comment: so when she(teacher) returns the paper, she will have surely cut marks for my answer, shall i argue that my answer is correct according to the question

Comment: I would respectfully request that she show where, as the question is stated on the paper, your failed to deliver an appropriate response. As others have pointed out, it is very likely that her intent was to have you alias a simple scaler types, but that intent was poorly conveyed if so, and without conveying it, you did the best you could under the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

But the right use of typedef is to create aliases for existing data types. If you use it to name an anonymous struct (it is a perfectly valid use) then it seems to miss the point of the lesson.

Your answer is valid indeed, the problem is that your teacher probably wanted to give another name to int.